# Struct member point at another struct member

Tags: c, pointers, struct

is it possible for struct member to point at another member from different struct?
I want to do something like reference table.

```
struct a {
    int a;
    int b;
};

struct b {
    * struct a.b;
};
```

A guess it's not possible since there is no memory allocated, but I'm open for suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just use a pointer

```
struct b 
{
    int* p ; //or an array of pointers if you need a table
} ;

struct a sa = { 1 , 2 } ;
struct b sb = { &sa.a } ;

printf("%d\n" , sb.p ) ;

sb.p = &sa.b ;    
printf("%d\n" , sb.p ) ;
```